# Does x contribute to y, independent of z?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am running into a problem answering the question in the title. All variables are numeric.

```
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x * z, data = data)
```

I have tried a pairwise t-test, but am unsure if this is the right approach, but I get an error message:

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) :
unique() applies only to vectors
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you add some sample data with `dput` to help us reproduce this? Thanks.

Comment: If the data has a large number of rows, `dput(head(data, 25))` should be enough. Also paste the results of `summary(lm1)` into your question and the code you used that produced the error message.

Comment: Hi @FlorisW, welcome to StackOverflow, you need to read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for you to know what elements to add in order to improve your question. This question is not a code/programming one, so it better fits in other forum like [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). To answer your question, after succesfully running your `lm` take `summary` and perform a individually significance test on `x:y` parameter estimation. It's a simple basic econometric problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct approach. You want to see that there is no interaction between the two variables, x and y (the coeffecient is the same).

As for the error: Can you check if **data** is a **dataframe**? Perhaps explicitly check or convert?

```
type(data)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x * z, data=data)
```

Comment: I think you forgot to update data: `data <- as.data.frame(data)`. Furthermore, see `attach` to avoid the `x_l <- data[,"x"]` and so on part, not recommend using `attach` that's why `data` argument is inside `lm`.